# searching value in spreadsheet columns with Google Ads Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google ads script to check if a certain text is already exist in my spreadsheet file.
If not, I want the function to return -1, if exist return the row it was found in.

I am using a loop to run on all the cells in the column and check each one.
In order to test it, I took of the cell's data and run the test, but it didn't find them equal...

here is the log for row #5:

row # 5 contains : mobileapp::2-com.rustybrick.shabbat but we look for : mobileapp::2-com.rustybrick.shabbat

enclose the script I use:

```
 function findInColumn(column, data)
{

  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    
  var SHEET_NAME = 'גליון 1';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREDSHEET_FILE);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var column = sheet.getRange(column + ":" + column);  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;  
  var data1 = data;
  var values = column.getValues();
  var row = 0;
  
      while ( values[row] !== data1 && row < lastRow ) 
{
    row++;
   
    if(values[row] === data1)
    {
     return row;
    }
    else
        {
          Logger.log("row # " + row + " contains : " + values[row] + " but we look for : " + data1);
        }    
  }

    return -1;
  }
```

So, my two questions are:

1. Why the script didn't recognize it's a match?
2. Is there a better or quicker way to do this search? now there are only 1K rows in the file, but it will become much higher soon

Answer (score 0):

### Findings

After replicating your script, here's what I have found:

- The `var values = column.getValues()` will only contain the the value on row 1 of the column because `column = sheet.getRange(column + ":" + column);` will only get value of range Row 1, Column 1 (e.g. the `column` paramter is set as 1). Thus, there's no match found.

### Solution

If I understand it correctly, here are your goals:

- Check & find a match on each cells of a column
- Return the **row #** of the matched cell ***OR*** return **-1** if there's no match found
- Find a better or quicker way to do the search

***You may try this simpler script:***

> A ***switch statement*** was used on the sample script instead of an ***if statement*** as it is more efficient, given you will have more than 1k of total rows. [See](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-vs-else/#:%7E:text=A%20switch%20statement%20is%20usually,a%20set%20of%20nested%20ifs.&text=Therefore%2C%20if%20we%20need%20to,a%20sequence%20of%20if%2Delses.)

```
function findInColumn(column, data)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREDSHEET_FILE_URL).getSheetByName('גליון 1');
  var total_rows = ss.getDataRange().getValues().length;
  var result = -1;

  Logger.log("==================\nCHECKING COLUMN #"+column + "\n==================\nDATA TO FIND:\n"+data+"\n==================");
  for(row=1; row<=total_rows; row++){
    var currentRowValue = ss.getRange(row,column).getValue();

    switch(currentRowValue) {
      case currentRowValue = data:
        Logger.log("Found a match on row #"+row);
        result = row;
        break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

### Test Results

**1.** Sample `גליון 1` Sheet with test values on Column 1:

[image]

**2.** Ran the `findInColumn(column, data)` with  ***1*** &
***"mobileapp::2-com.rustybrick.shabbat"*** as parameter values on a testing function and the result returned row **3.0** :

[image]

**3.** If there will be no match found, the returned result will be **-1.0**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

When I try to use your code, I got an error:
Cannot convert C to (class). This error refers to code line 9

Comment: Hmm... that's a different error. Can you share your complete script on your original post by editing it? How do you run the findInColumn(column, data) function specifically?

Comment: Do you specifically put letter "C" as the column value on your findInColumn(column, data) function?